# Marketing Cloud and Google Analytics (Not GA360)

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

I'm trying to connect our Marketing Cloud account with our Google Analytics account so that we can pass Marketing Cloud activity through to Google. I've looked all over for help articles and set up guides but only get sent to GA 360 articles.

I want to be able to set up something similar to below but all I'm directed to is Parameter Manager. Are there prerequisite steps I need to configure before setting the parameters? Do I not need need to share the Collect Code with GA or perform a system-level handshake?

```
?⁠utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=[Channel]&utm_campaign=[Set per Message]&utm_term=[Link Alias]&utm_content=[Content AssetID]&utm_id=[JourneyID]&sfmc_id=[ContactID]&sfmc_activityid=[ActivityID]
```

It would be great if someone could add clarity as I'm struggling to find the answer I need.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. 

Parameter manager is the way to make traffic directed from your emails generated in Marketing Cloud make sense to Google Analytics on a website. 
The assumption being that you direct traffic to a webpage that has GA enabled and the GA Collect Code established, like a webshop. 

If you want to do similar things like this on Cloudpages, you'd have to add the Collect Code to your Cloudpages.

Comment: Thanks @JonasLamberty. I just want to be able to pass through source, channel, campaign, term, content and id through to our GA account so they can see activity generated by the marketing team.

Comment: Hi, in that case, Parameter manager _is_ the answer. A GA tracking code on a website waits for input from these standardized parameters. There is no handshake. The "handshake" if you will, is that you use parameters that Google Analytics natively understands and send them to the page. GA on the page then reads out what's in the parameters and associates the traffic to e.g. "source: marketing cloud", "campaign: your Email campaign ID".

Comment: Thanks so much, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembled from the comments:

Parameter manager is the way to make traffic directed from your emails generated in Marketing Cloud make sense to Google Analytics on a website. The assumption being that you direct traffic to a webpage that has GA enabled and the GA Collect Code established, like a webshop. If you want to do similar things like this on Cloudpages, you'd have to add the Collect Code to your Cloudpages.

So, for passing parameters to your existing non-Cloudpage Websites, Parameter manager *is* the answer. A GA tracking code on a website waits for input from these standardized parameters. There is no handshake. The "handshake" if you will, is that you use parameters that Google Analytics natively understands and send them to the page. GA on the page then reads out what's in the parameters and associates the traffic to e.g. "source: marketing cloud", "campaign: your Email campaign ID".